# Проверка на соответствие строки шаблону, регулярка

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Сразу оговорюсь, что в регулярках очень слаб.
Необходимо доработать регулярное выражения для проверки соответствия строки некоему шаблону текста.

Додумался пока что только к такому коду:

```
Regex template = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]{1,}.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}");
string str = "";
while ((str = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} a valid input", str, template.IsMatch(str) ? "is " : "is not ");
   }
```

Но, в работе моего регулярного выражения (`[a-zA-Z]{1,}.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}`) есть минус, а именно - оно пропускает входную строку вида **а.а.а.а.а** (т.е., с любым к-ство знаков **.**, а этого - не нужно).

**Входящая строка должна соответствовать такому шаблону:**

> Имя Фамилия_Группа_Название работы

Разделитель между полями - нижнее подчеркивание (**_**).

Символы могут быть любыми, в первой паре - без цифр.

В первом поле - максимум три слова с любым к-ством символов, но > 2.

Во втором и третьем поле - сколько угодно символов и цифр, разделители везде для полей - пробелы.

В виду своей неграмотности в регулярных выражениях, прошу помощи.

Comment: Используйте в регулярке обозначение начала строки `^` и ее конца `$`.

Comment: Поставь начало строки с большой буквы.

Comment: А с каким количеством знаков нужно? И там пробел ешё - `\w{2,}\.\s+`

Comment: Решение может считаться правильным, если оно соответствует требованиям. Каковы требования данной задачи?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew я добавил требования.

Comment: Нет, это не требования. Это даже не пример. Тут можно гадать и дальше: 1) Какие буквы - кириллица, латинница, любые? 2) Что является разделителем: точка, нижнее подчеркивание, любой отличный от буквы/цифры знак? 3) Сколько может быть слов в поле  и каковы разделители между этими словами? Почитайте о регулярных выражениях, поймите, как они работают, тогда поймёте, как правильно задать вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Углубившись и почитав о **регулярных выражениях** я нашел решение этой проблемы.

Это регулярка следующего вида:

```
^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я ]+_[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9-]+_([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9 -])+$
```

Начало строки (первая пара) - любые буквы и пробел.

Во второй паре, обозначающей группу студента - любые буквы и цифры, а так же дефис.

Третья пара аналогична второй, плюс добавлен пробел и символизирует конец строки. Если разделителей будет больше - строка не пройдет.

Разделителем является нижнее подчеркивание.